# Need help using multi curl in php to upload files

Tags: php, curl

My current script to upload photos goes like this:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

I can have up to 1000 files to upload to a remote server and it can take a long time for curl to process everything. The solution seems to be multi-curl, however there is a unique aspect:

what I need from multi-curl is to save the response into an array like `$upload_results[] = array($file, 'response')`

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this can be done by creating the handles in an array with the file names as keys and then reading the results into another array with the same keys.

```
function uploadLotsOfFiles($files) {
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $handles = array();
    $results = array();

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $handles[$file] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handles[$file], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //File reading code and other options from your question go here

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $handles[$file]);
    }

    $running = 0;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        curl_multi_select($mh); //Prevent eating CPU
    } while($running > 0);
    foreach($handles as $file => $handle) {
        $results[$file] = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handle);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

If you really need the result to be in the format you specified (which I don't recommend since it's less elegant than using the file as a key):

```
$results[] = array($file, curl_multi_getcontent($handle));
```

Can be used in place of `$results[$file] = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);`

Comment: Thank you. I did implement your code, however I keep on getting an error that `(null)(): 490 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: @user2029890 That error can happen when trying to add a handle with some kind of problem. In particular, ensure that the URL is valid and properly encoded (no unencoded spaces, etc.)

Comment: I double-checked. The URL seems fine, its the same URL I use for regular curl. Could it be anything else?

Comment: @user2029890 Try putting `echo $file . '<br>';` before the `curl_multi_add_handle` to see which file it's failing on (which will be the last echo'd file)